# Peticiones web tipo %D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%

Tags: linux, apache

En un servidor web estoy recibiendo este tipo de peticiones:

```
114.119.159.70 - - [22/Jul/2021:21:46:03 +0200] "GET /%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94 HTTP/1.1" 404 3530 182626
```

Alguien sabe que son este tipo de peticiones? Hay forma de bloquear este tipo de peticiones?

Gracias!

Comment: Esa petición esta enviando caracteres URL-encoded para ver qué hace tu servidor con ellos. Si haces URL decode de esa petición, sale `מדינות/לימודי-רפואה-בסלובקיה/לימודי-רפואה-בסלובקיה-הקדמה`. La pregunta es por qué quieres bloquearlas. Esencialmente te pueden enviar cualquier cosa en el get, depende de cuál es tu tráfico esperado y hacia qué recursos.

Comment: Me resulta curioso este tipo de URL. La verdad, mi server no espera ninguna petición de este tipo pues es una tienda online.

Comment: algún bot le pifio al domain [PAÍSES / ESTUDIOS-MEDICOS-ESLOVAQUIA / ESTUDIOS-MEDICOS-ESLOVAQUIA-INTRODUCCION](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=es&text=%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%2F%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94%2F%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94&op=translate)